# Single Die Roll Counter Wrap Around Nested Ternary Conditional

Tags: digital-logic, vhdl, verilog, system-verilog

I have to emulate a single die roll, therefore it needs to wrap back to one at 6. 
`` `D1 `` and `` `D6 `` correspond to my 3-bit state encoding of the die at value 1 an 6, respectively.
`in` corresponds to the switch roll, if the switch is on then the dice is rolling and value increments if not then it simply equals the last value given. *I need equal probability so no I can't just ignore any values.*

My problem is this: 
I am trying to use a ternary conditional within one. 
I'm hoping to stop the roll at `` `D6 `` and just wrap to `` `D1 ``, if not then `` `D6 ``.

```
assign next  = in ?((count == `D6) ? `D1 :(count + 1)) : count;

DFF state_register(clk, next, state);
```

I don't think my conditional is right. Any help on reading it properly?

Comment: it's correct expcet 'D6 needs to be `D6. :)

Comment: You can do just "counter = (counter + 1) % 6;" and attach the ternary like so "assign next = in ? (count + 1) % 6 : count;"

Comment: Hmm I see at 7 it would give me 1 and then at 8 it would give me 2. It would give appearance of wraparound, however at 6, 6 % 6 = 1. I need 6 included, also i would get large numbers which I would have to store and operate on. This keeps it within the 1 to 6 range with wraparound, with small numbers.

Comment: just saw the rest of the comment, i gotcha now! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer:

it's correct expcet 'D6 needs to be `D6. :)`
D6 because i defined it above my module. I just used an apostrophe which it is not.

Besides, how does this all work? 
Well ternary conditionals work as so:  `variable = conditional ? true : false;`

so `next = count` if my `in` is false.

Now what I have here is when it is true there is a nested ternary conditional:

''(count == `D6) ? 'D1 : (count + 1)``

so if count is equal to my `D6 (my die has a value of 6) then I need it to wrap around to`D1 (die of value 1), because the die here can't have value 7, 8, 9, etc. We want the counting to wrap back around.

Therefore,

when `in` is true and `count` is not ``` D6 then I count up.
when  ``in`` is true and ``count`` is ```D6  then I make `next` equal to `D1 
when `in` is false then `next` is just equal to count, meaning it stays current and no "roll" is recorded.

Hope that all makes sense!